# Bidirectional bubble sort using goto

Tags: c++, array, sorting

I am aware of Dijkstra's paper on why `goto` is harmful, but I thought it would still be fun to make a bidirectional bubble sort using `goto`. So I did. I thought I'd share the code here. Cheers!

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int size){
    int counter = 0;
BottomUp: //This starts with the lowest array index and goes up to the highest
    if(size == 1)
        return;
    counter += 1;
    if(arr[counter] < arr[counter - 1])
        swap(arr[counter], arr[counter - 1]);

    if(counter < size - 1)
        goto BottomUp;
    counter += 1;
TopDown: //This starts from the highest array index and goes back down to the lowest
    counter -= 1;
    if(arr[counter] < arr[counter - 1])
        swap(arr[counter], arr[counter - 1]);

    if(counter > 1)
        goto TopDown;
    else{
        counter = 0;
        size -= 1;
        goto BottomUp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read Knuth's work on how `goto` can be more elegant and efficient in certain contexts? I guess we'll find out how elegant your use of `goto`s is...

Comment: This can easily be rewritten to nested loops: `for(;;) { BottomUp: do { ... } while (counter >= size - 1); counter += 1; TopDown: do { .. } while (counter <= 1); conter = 0; size -= 1; }`. I am not against using `goto` if you really need them and I hate warnings from C++ compilers about passing variable initialization I am not using after the label, which makes using `goto` even harder for no real reason (other than stupidity of compiler throwing unnecessary warnings at me), but this is not good usage of `goto`.

Comment: HAve you written the same algorthim without using goto. Then compared them to see which is more readable?

Comment: @Martin York -- no, I just programmed this for fun.

Comment: @firda That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: `goto` is a tool that easily can be abused. Still there are quite a few useful use cases, e. g. exiting quickly nested loops. Sometimes, it can be useful for optimising some performance critical hotspots (before you start writing assembler code instead). It is just like an axe: you can kill people with, but you can chop the wood for your next barbecue as well...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are deliberately using `goto`, which violates the "Do you want this to be good code?" rule in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Other than the elephant in the room (this isn't a justified use of `goto`), I have some other nitpicks:

- I'm uncomfortable passing an array as an argument. A pointer - sure; a reference to an array - sure. Since you're in C++ I'd go with the reference-to-array.
- The various `+= 1` and `-= 1` can simply be `++` and `--`.
- Your `else` isn't necessary. You've already jumped prior to that line.